# Rails 3.2 app: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass for a Class that exists and renders on page just fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am running a pretty straight forward Rails 3.2 app on Dreamhost (I know its lame).

The error is:

```
NoMethodError in Products#edit

Showing /home/emeraldcityguitars/emeraldcityguitars.com/releases/20120318040051/app/views/products/edit.html.erb where line #47 raised:

undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #47):

44:   <div id="interior_sub_head"><h5 id="sub_green_head"><%= @product.title %></h5></div>
45:   <div id="interior_pad">
46: 
47:     <%= nested_form_for @product, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
48:     <%= f.error_messages %>
49: 
50:     <fieldset>
```

It sounds like @product is returning nil, but if you look at line 44, it didn't error when requesting @product in that case?

any ideas?

EDIT

Full Product#edit view: https://gist.github.com/2081340

+

_photo_fields.html view: https://gist.github.com/5af2f88f29c21e24b42c

Thanks

Comment: More code needed. Show the outer `form_for`. Error is probably the wrong block variable being used somewhere (`|f|` is a block variable).

Comment: This might also be a bug in the esteemed Ryan Bates' `nested_form_for` gem.

Comment: any ideas?  this app is in production and this Class can't be CRUD'd

Comment: What happens if you get rid of line 91? `<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Photo", :photos %></p>` See if the error is any different.

Comment: full error tracing is needed. Error somewhere in ActionView/NestedForm - need to know in which line/method it occurs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I made two changes, unfortunately not separately, and one or both solved the problem.

First, in your controller do you build a photo in your edit method?

```
@product.photos.build if @product.photos.empty?
```

I found that in the comments on this [blog post](http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2010/10/07/dynamic-nested-froms-with-the-nested-form-gem.html).

Second, I added a symbol for the nested class to the 'link_to_add' line, which you already have.

Comment: Does the link to 'show' in the product view work? That would prove that *@product* is non-nil. The next thing to verify is that the associations are set up properly, the product model has "accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos", and there is a photo instance associated with *@product*.

Comment: Can you show the associations between Product and Photo models, and the 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' line in the Product model?

Answer (score 0):

I was switching from a has_many to has_one and was getting this same error.  Azolo's response fixed my issue.

Removed the <%= f.link_to_add......%> tag and all is working nicely!